# Holder inequality for a general rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, norms

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $p,q \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. I am interested to prove the following:

$$ \|A\|_{p}=\|A^T\|_q$$

I have tried using Holder Inequality for vectors $Ax$ and $A^Ty$ and thereby mapping back to the original matrix norm using basic properties but I am unable to proceed further because the vector sizes are different.

Is there any other way to prove the same?

Comment: Unfortunately, the notation $\|A\|_p$ is used for several different matrix norms.  Which one are you using?

Comment: Here, I mean vector-induced norm. Sorry for not mentioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
LHS&=& \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^m\backslash \{0\},y\in \mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}} \frac{|x^TAy|}{\|x\|_q\|y\|_p}\\
&\leq& \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^m\backslash \{0\},y\in \mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}} \frac{ \|x\|_q\|Ay\|_p}{\|x\|_q\|y\|_p}\\
&=& \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^m\backslash \{0\},y\in \mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}} \frac{\|Ay\|_p}{\|y\|_p}\\
&=&\|A\|_p.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Similarly $LHS\leq \|A^T\|_q$. Note that by compactness argument there exist $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ s.t. $\|Ay\|_p=\|A\|_p\|y\|_p$. We then have equality by choosing $x=sign(Ay).*|Ay|.^{p/q}$ where $.$ denotes element wise operation. Hence we have
$$
\|A\|_p=LHS=\|A^T\|_q.
$$

Comment: So we are choosing x such that x and Ay are related by the relation you gave, in order to turn the inequality into an equality. But will that x correspond to the vector induced norm of the transpose of A?